# Handle press of arrow in input element knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I am using `knockout` and I have a normal HTML input element.
I want to handle the press of `up arrow`, `down arrow`, `left arrow` and `right arrow` for this input **using Knockout way, not any other workaround**

here is what I tried

```
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: $data, event: {keypress: $parent.HandleMove}" />
```

but the `HandleMove` function is fired with all keys **except** `up arrow`, `down arrow`, `left arrow` and `right arrow` 
 I think the reason of that, is being those events handled by something else (to make navigation of characters inside the input itself, like going character left, character right and ....)

**NOTE** I have done a lot of search before putting this question
here are the results

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970751) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548678) are not acceptable for me because they handle the event globally using the `$(window)` jQuery element, and I do not want to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `keypress` event is only fired for "character" keys so not for the arrows key.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress):

> The keypress event is fired when a key is pressed down and that key normally produces a character value

So you need to use `keydown` or `keyup` event to capture the arrow keys:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: $data, event: {keydown: $parent.HandleMove}" />
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/440e4wL3/).